# Database connection denied by using 127.0.0.1 in cakephp project on SVN

Tags: php, cakephp, svn

I am working on a CakePHP project, and trying to change host name localhost with 127.0.0.1. It works fine on localhost, but when I try to commit the file on SVN then the site doesn't work and it gives database connection failed error.

Comment: Make sure the user can connect to localhost in MySQL

Comment: Do you get the same error with `::1`? This is the address for localhost with IPv6 (which is the default on some recent Windows OS, afaik)

Comment: @ Pierre Prinetti : yes it is giving the same error for ::1 also

Comment: What is actually the problem? You’ve changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and it stopped working? Or, when you run your code locally, it works, but on remote server, it does not? Which piece of code exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Not all hosting providers supporting "localhost". In many hosting providers, they keep their database in seperate server.

Such things, you might not able to get at first. I advice you to go in your control panel and try to find out what is your database connection url.

Hope this helps!!

P.S. Kindly never share your details over community for quick solutions.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but what that P.S. piece is...?

Comment: Sometimes, people asking for CPanel details to setup details for you. So Just do not share.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood :) Yes, you should never give your server details.